# nodeJS + Express-Session error: Cannot set property 'loggedin' of undefined`

Tags: node.js, session-variables

I am trying to create a session variable (loggedin) if the user log in, but I get `TypeError: Cannot set property 'loggedin' of undefined`. I can't figure out why it does not work. I have tried to reinstall session records and alsp change place for it in the code but still the same error. Any idea why I get this error?

Here is the code:

```
   var mysql = require('mysql');
    var express = require('express'); 
    var session = require('express-session'); 
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
    var path = require('path');
    var app = express();

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'root',
            password : 'password',
            database : 'database'
        });

app.use(session({secret: 'secret', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true})); //Session setup

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const router6 = express.Router();

app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public'))); 

router6.get('/login', function(request, response) {
response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
}); 


//*** SESSION VARIABLE SET BELOW ***// 
//Post for authentication, from form action

router6.post('/authThis', function(request, response) { 
   let username = request.body.username; 
   let password = request.body.password;
   console.log(username + password)

   if (username && password) { 
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) { 
        if (results.length > 0) { 
            request.session.loggedin = true; //Error here. Says cannot set loggedin property
            request.session.username = username; 
            response.redirect('/');
            } else {
                    response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!'); 
                }           
                response.end();
            });
        } else {
            response.send('Please enter Username and Password!'); //om anv & lös inte fyllts i.
            response.end();
        }
        });


//******
        module.exports = router6;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exporting the router, which should be the app.

So `app` has access to all middleware, `router6` doesn't.

`router6` is an instance of `app`. You ask the `app` instance to use session. But you actually export the router.

So `module.exports = app;` should fix this.