# How do I access a session in another route or function in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am building a platform where a teacher can keep track of student's progress. I'm a beginner at nodeJS. I am trying to authorize the user using sessions. I am using mysql for database.

I tried initiating the session in app.js and importing the app in authcontroller and then saving the loggedin as true but it gives back this error: 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'loggedin' of undefined at Query.onResult (E:\freelance\weloveworksheets\controller\auth.js:50:38)'

Working directory:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfcLF.jpg

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
var createError = require('http-errors');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require('ejs');
var flash = require('express-flash');
const studentRoutes =  require("./routes/student");
const homeRoutes =  require("./routes/home");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const mysqlConnection = require('./database');
const ejsLint = require('ejs-lint');
const serveIndex = require('serve-index');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

var session = require('express-session');


const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use( express.static( "public" ) );
app.use('/student', studentRoutes);
app.use('/', homeRoutes);
app.use('/auth',authRoutes);
app.use(express.json());
// SET VIEW ENGINE
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views','views');

app.use(flash());


app.use(session({ 
  secret: '123456cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}));

// USE BODY-PARSER MIDDLEWARE
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.listen('3000',()=>{
    console.log("server started on port 3000");
});

module.exports = app;
```

auth.js(router)

```
const express = require ('express');
const router = express();

const mysqlConnection = require("../database");
var session = require('express-session');
const ejs = require('ejs');
router.use( express.static( "public" ) );
const authController = require("../controller/auth");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");



router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));


router.post('/register',authController.register);

router.post('/login',authController.login);

module.exports = router;
```

auth.js(controller)

```
const mysqlConnection = require("../database");
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const session = require("express-session");
const app = require('../app');
exports.register = (req,res)=> {
        console.log(req.body);
        
        const {name,email,password,confirmPassword} = req.body;
        console.log(name);
        mysqlConnection.query('SELECT email FROM teachers WHERE email = ?',[email], async (err,results)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            if(results.length>0){
                return res.render('register',{
                    message: 'That email is already in use'
                });

            }
            else if(password !== confirmPassword){
                return res.render('register',{
                    message: 'Passwords do not match'
                });
            }
            
            let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
            

            mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO teachers SET ?',{name:name,email:email,password:hashedPassword},(err,results)=>{
                if(err) throw err;
                else{
                    res.redirect('/login');
                }
            });
        })
       
}
exports.login = (req,res)=> {
    
    console.log(req.body);
    const {email,password} = req.body;
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE email=?',[email],async(err,results)=>{
        if(!results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password,results[0].password))){
            res.render('login',{
                message:'E-mail or password is incorrect'
            })
        }
        else{                  
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.user = results;
                var sess = req.session;
                res.redirect('/student');
        }
        
    })
}

exports.authorize = (req,res)=>{
    
    console.log(req.session);
}
```

It works fine if I initiate the session from auth.js controller but I don't know how to access the session for authorize further routes. Sorry if this is silly I am a beginner, I tried searching online but I couldn't find or understand how to implement it. Thanks for your time :)

I found a similar issue but the suggested answer isn't working
[nodeJS + Express-Session error: Cannot set property 'loggedin' of undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866429/nodejs-express-session-error-cannot-set-property-loggedin-of-undefined?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this in app.js

```
...
...

const auth = require('path_to_auth.js') // Require the auth.js file here
app.use('/auth', auth) // all request to /auth will now go to auth.js
...


// Now in a route
app.get('/', checkSession, (req, res) => {
    // Everything here will execute only if session exists.
    // so now send your request to /auth like below    
    req.redirect('/auth')
    // Then at your auth you will be able to use req.session
})


// Middleware to check session validity
function checkSession(req, res, next) {
    if (if_ssesion_exist) {// If session exists call next..
        next()
    }
    else {
        //create a session and redirect to '/'         
    }

}
```

Comment: I've required and stored the auth route already in authroute consant in app.js . But I don't get how I can check if the session exists in the checkSession function

Comment: In your auth.js file you have required app.js in a variable **app** but it is not used anywhere in the code.